# Best way to develop and test an ASP.NET Core web api locally

Tags: asp.net-web-api, client, local

I am looking at developing a web api for my business rules/database access.

I can use Postman to test the api locally but I also need to develop the client web site.

Is it just a case of running the web api locally and then developing the client site to use the local web api urls?

e.g. http://localhost/api/getcustomer/1

Also when it eventually goes live what do I need to look into in order to secure it all?

Regards

Comment: [This should help](https://dzone.com/articles/authentication-in-aspnet-core-for-your-web-api-and)

Comment: Thanks for that Nilay. That will help on the security side.